# I need to create a folder by using codeigniter without button click

Tags: codeigniter

I need to create a folder to store user information at login. One login button should perform 2 actions.

They are

1. Login
2. Create folder

I need this in CODEIGNITER, please someone help me, I've been stuck with this for 4 weeks.

This is my code

```
<?php
ob_start();
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class LoginTwo extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("login_model", "login");

    }
public function login()
{
    $username = $this->input->post("username");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    $isCorrect = $this->login->validate_user($username, $password);

    if($isCorrect)
    {
        // Start your user session

        $dirName = $username;
        $dirPath = "folder/".$dirName."/";

        if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
            mkdir("folder/" . $dirName, 0777, true);
        }

        redirect("your user page");
    }
    else
    {
        redirect("homepage");
    }
}
}?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything??? Please show your code.

Comment: Dear kishor I add what i have tried yet..My project supervisor forces me to create this folder without a button click, still I am an intern am confused..help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Is your code getting any error? what is the error message?

Comment: Yes i this is the error Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: foldername

Comment: Whatever you tried, from that code I come to know that you misunderstood codeigniter very badly. You need to write code in the function of login (in controller).

Comment: Sorry to hear I tried that also,,this code works one time .But when i write in controller nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below mentioned solutions.

```
$path = FCPATH.'/uploads/';
$new_directory = 'name';
mkdir($path.$name,0755,TRUE);
```

In this

- First_Param: pathname :Name of directory
- Second_Param: mode: Permissions
- Third Param : recursive : Allows the creation of nested directories

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code. You need to fit your requirements within this code block (you can change it if you have to do something more).

**You controller function :**

```
public function login()
{
    $username = $this->input->post("username");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    $isCorrect = $this->user_model->checkCredentials($username, $password);

    if($isCorrect)
    {
        // Start your user session

        $dirName = $username;
        $dirPath = "folder/".$dirName."/";

        if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
            mkdir("folder/" . $dirName, 0777, true);
        }

        redirect("your user page");
    }
    else
    {
        redirect("homepage");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Kishor I edit my code according to your advice. I prepare a folder name"folder" in root folder in CPanel. But for my bad luck it was not work.I have edit above my latest code.Thank you very much for your effort. Please do something more if you can

Comment: Please first you have to test it on your localhost then work on live server. Also please modify the code as per your requirement, not as per my suggestion. It is just the way not full resolution.